# Is it possible to preview ffmpeg's output using ffplay in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, ffmpeg, video-processing, mobile-ffmpeg

**Am building a mobile-based video editor using ffmpeg-kit/react-native**  
 https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native. 
 when I use complex filter it took me approx 0.5-1 mins to apply filter and then I become able to present how the filter looks like. 
What I want is to show a real quick preview before applying the filter.
 
 May applications like TikTok are using gl-view to mimic the filter before applying it (to achieve the real quick preview). 
 After exploring FFmpeg I came to know ffplay https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html allows us to preview filters before actually applying them.
 **So the question is how can I use ffplay in my mobile app android or ios. I tried exploring mobile-FFmpeg but not able to find any clue.**  *Please ignore my mistakes in English*

Comment: `ffplay -vf "filter1,filter2,filter3" input.mp4` is a simplistic example. Your question lacks details so we are unable to provide more specific help.

Comment: Hey, @llogan thanks for your response, I have updated my question please review it.